# Fail to build for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, packaging

I try and build my package for Ubuntu but I can't understand the error. I get this

```
debuild -S -sa
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S -sa
dpkg-buildpackage: source package opsh
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.1-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Niklas Rosencrantz <nik@kth.se>
 dpkg-source --before-build opsh
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean  --with autotools_dev
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_autotools-dev_restoreconfig
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b opsh
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building opsh using existing ./opsh_0.1.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: local changes detected, the modified files are:
 opsh/src/check.t
dpkg-source: error: aborting due to unexpected upstream changes, see /tmp/opsh_0.1-1.diff.TooA5f
dpkg-source: info: you can integrate the local changes with dpkg-source --commit
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b opsh gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S -sa failed
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is

```
dpkg-source: info: local changes detected, the modified files are:
 opsh/src/check.t
```

That means that `opsh/src/check.t` doesn’t match the contents of `opsh_0.1.orig.tar.gz`. In Debian packages, any changes to a file outside the `debian` directory must be reversible. Since you’re using “3.0 (quilt)” packaging, the best way to handle this is to add a patch. The [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/UsingQuilt) has the details, but the error message gives you a quick solution to turn your changes into a patch:

```
dpkg-source --commit
```

You’ll need to rename and edit the patch appropriately (as generated, it should contain enough comments for you to figure things out).

You should only do this if the file really is changed in a way significant for the build. If it’s a file left over from a previous build, not shipped in the original tarball, you should instead add it to `debian/clean` so that it gets removed at the start of the build. This can also apply to files which are shipped in the tarball but get fully regenerated during the build.